# I get a "only parameterless constructors and initializers are supported in linq to entities" error

Tags: linq-to-entities

I have this method in my application and I get the "only..." error. Any ideas as to why??

```
 public IEnumerable<HistoriekStatusDto> GetStatusItems(long aanvraagId)
        {
            return Context.DossierStatusHistoriekJNSet.Where(dsh => dsh.DossierversieId == aanvraagId)
                .Select(x => new HistoriekStatusDto
                {
                    Versie = Context.DossierVersieJNSet.Where(dv => dv.DossierVersieId == x.DossierversieId).Select(t => t.Versie).FirstOrDefault(),
                    Status = x.Status,
                    DossierType = x.Dossiertype,
                    Uitvoerder = x.Uitvoerder,
                    Datum = new DateTime(x.DateTimeJN)
                }).ToList();
        }
```

Comment: I think well need to see (1) the definition of `HistoriekStatusDto`, (2) your `DbContext` derived type, and (3) the definition of `DossierStatusHistoriekJNSet`.

Answer (score 0):

All I needed was a **.AsEnumerable()**

```
public IEnumerable<HistoriekStatusDto> GetStatusItems(long aanvraagId)
        {

            return Context.DossierStatusHistoriekJNSet.Where(dsh => dsh.DossierversieId == aanvraagId)**.AsEnumerable()**
                .Select(x => new HistoriekStatusDto
                {
                    Versie = Context.DossierVersieJNSet.Where(dv => dv.DossierVersieId == x.DossierversieId).FirstOrDefault().Versie,
                    Status = x.Status,
                    DossierType = x.Dossiertype,
                    Uitvoerder = x.Uitvoerder,
                    Datum = new DateTime(x.DateTimeJN)
                }).ToList();
        }
```